# Mpi file not recognized?

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to compile some mpi files on Ubuntu I installed the library using this code

```
 sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc
```

and tried to compile this simple hello world program

```
 /* C Example */
 #include <mpi.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
int rank, size;

MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);      /* starts MPI */
MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);        /* get current process id */
MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);        /* get number of processes */
printf( "Hello world from process %d of %dn", rank, size );
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

the hello file is on the desktop I used this command

```
 mpicc mpi_hello.c -o hello
```

as you can see The library is well installed yet I can't seem to compile any program,

```
  Reading state information... Done
  libcr-dev is already the newest version.
  mpich2 is already the newest version.
  mpich2-doc is already the newest version.
```

here is the error I keep getting for any mpi Program I try and compile

```
 gcc: error: mpi_hello.c: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not in the desktop directory, try to move to the desktop and compile again.

```
cd ~/Desktop
mpicc mpi_hello.c -o hello
```